# IE8: Common performance glitches with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

IE8 and Javascript in general: what are the common problems causing performance glitches on IE8? Does anybody know of a collection of issues and things to avoid when developing scripts for IE8?
It is very easy to produce script that runs in 200ms on Firefox and 10 seconds on IE8, so I'm wondering if there's a comprehensive list of dos and donts somewhere?

Please note that I'm not interested in answers like "use JQuery" - I am interested in the issues.

René

Comment: Can you provide the example code which would run in 200ms and 10s on IE8?

Comment: There are extreme situations with string concatenation for example. Unluckily I cannot find the demo anymore. Another issue seems to be style changes, then access offsetWidth/offsetHeight which causes a re-layout. Not a big deal on FF but done often enough, rendering times explode on IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this video: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/extreme-javascript-performance/ - the guy offers some benchmarks that might give you an idea regarding what's slow and in which browsers (surprisingly, Firefox's JS engine turned out damn slow).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code:

```
$('#tasks').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bScrollInfinite": true,
                "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "sScrollY": "450px"
});
```

Where is says 450px, i had previously put a "," after it. In IE this errored and it took me ages to find that damn comma!

Comment: I used to do that all the time. Tools like http://www.jslint.com/ and http://www.javascriptlint.com/ are essential and will catch this mistake. If you use TextMate, there’s a bundle called JSTools that will run JSLint on your code every time you hit save.

Comment: nice, thanks for that. I pretty much rely on Firebug for my fault-finding nowadays!